# List defined in __init__ seems to be global

Tags: python-3.x

In python 3.7, I'm trying to use an instance-specific list and for some reason, it behaves like a class attribute.

```
class Acc:
    def __init__(self, items = []):
        self.items = items

    def add(self, value):
        self.items.append(value)
```

Then I use

```
a = Acc()
b = Acc()
a.add(42)
print(b.items)
```

and get `[42]`. Why?

Comment: Default arguments are evaluated *when the function is created*, not each time the function is called. You stored a single mutable object in the function defaults..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Honestly, I'm still confused.. I got the `def foo(a=[])` case from the link, but here it seems even a bit more strange. Is the `__init__` function "created" once, or twice, in my code?

Comment: Just once. The `Acc()` call only **calls** it, indirectly (the `__new__` method is called and produces an instance object, then `__init__()` is called on that). Both times the `self.items` attribute is added which is a reference to the same list object.

Comment: Note that `self.items = items` does not create a copy here.